# Implement a Whitelist on Relational Databases

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a growing web system of around 30,000 users.

There's a few actions on the web system that are disabled for most users. But some trusted clients might be given the privilege to use them.

I already have an object that handles the permissions for each user (get/set). Those permissions are represented in each user database entry as an Integer Field (each bit is a permission).

In my first option I would add a new permission field on my permission manager object for each whitelist that I would want to implement. Then when I would like to know if the current user is on the whitelist, I would call this object and check that permission.

But if would show to the admin a whitelist (display, edit, delete, etc), then I would have to create a permission manager object 30,000 times and test each permission. Which I think is very wasteful.

My second option is to create a new table `whitelists` and each row would be a different whitelist, then in a `TEXT` field I would write a comma separated list of users ids. The problem: `TEXT` `VARCHAR` or any kind of text field has a character count limit.

I think that the most efficient way is the second option since it's improbable that I would put more than 100 users in the whitelist.

But there's a better implementation?

Maybe I could add a new method to my permission manager object that would use only one query to build lists for a selected permission.

Comment: You can store the whitelist-to-users relationship in any format you like in your web app, but in database, you'd better stick to the one-to-many relationship instead of the text format. You can set up a new whiltelist-users table so you don't have to scan the whole user table for specified white-list users.